# What is the preferred Inheritance for ERC20 token and why?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin, inheritance, burn

I tried to deploy both ERC20 contracts with burn functionality over the remix and both seems to work fine, I am confused if one way should be preferred over the other. Since, [openzeppelin contract wizard](https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/) seems to implement the first way but for me the second also works just fine. Can someone point out where I am going wrong, inheritance is getting confusing for me.

```
    pragma solidity ^0.8.4;
    
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
    import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
    
    contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable {
        constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
           _mint(msg.sender, 2000 * 10 ** decimals());
}
    }
```

OR

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20Burnable {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 2000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ERC20Burnable inherits ERC20 contract so both ways are same.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol

Inheriting ERC20 contract as well explicitly in your contract and initializing it makes it a bit more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

Found this openzeppelin's discussion
[openzeppelin-contracts github discussion](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/commit/b8ab763581f8705fec306903659200fe753b68c3#r50166460)